# How do I replace OpenOffice 3.2.0 with OpenOffice 3.3.0?

Tags: openoffice.org

I wanted to install OpenOffice 3.3.0, but it was installed alongside OpenOffice 3.2.0 instead of replacing it

How do I upgrade 3.2.0 to 3.3.0?

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to install OpenOffice and not LibreOffice 3.3.0? If you want to install LibreOffice, you'll have to remove OpenOffice first.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing Openoffice prior to the new install?

You can do this via synaptic and/or the next command should work:

```
sudo apt-get remove openoffice
```

You will be asked to enter your password, after which the application will be removed, then try to install the new version as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you manually installed openoffice.org using a .deb file and thats why it installed under the /opt directory alongside your current installation.Follow the steps in the post above and you would be fine, though i advise you to stick to the distrubution supported version of Oo.